# How to get user system details from a php script running on a linux machine?

Tags: php, linux

when a user access a web link, i would like to show the following details of the user

- User name of user running the script
- workstation name (if he is accessing the web link in a browser from a windows machine then the name of the machine)

user environment is LAMP (linux, Apache web server, mysql Database, PHP)

tried php `exec` but it returns `apache` the owner of the php script and not the user accessing it from web link (the script resides in a remote linux server and user access is through a browser link only no direct machine access)

```
<?php
echo exec('whoami');
?>
```

so my question is since it is a link is there browser only restrictions and cant access system parameters?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Your php script runs on the server and is executed by the webserver (or fcgi module or whatever). So 'apache' is expected. The person requesting the result of your php script doesn't tell you his name unless you implement some authentication (see the apache documentation for that).
You might get some information you want to have from the request header, it at least contains the address of the requester (but not the hostname and you cannot _expect_ being able to get the user's Windows machine name from an IP address normally).

Comment: looking clear there....So is it `LDAP AUTH` which I should opt for and then retrieve details once user is logged in?

Comment: If ldap is the right one for you, I cannot say. But yes, you pick an authentication scheme and _then_ your php script will be able to refer to the results thereof. If someone authenticates as Bob then you can use that value in your script.

Answer (score 0):

For a web link, I think it's not possible. Because the PHP script is running on a remote server and a remote user is accessing the script via a web link. There'a no way to determine the name of the remote user and machine name. There are a very limited amount of data which is transferred via browser to the server side. You can try to check `$_SERVER` variable to check the details.
But trust me, your requirement doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: `$_SERVER` will not be accurate if the request is routed through proxy servers

basically i just want to know the username of the user accessing the script and their `windows` system name>>>

the script is always accessed from windows machines most of the time

Comment: Sadly, in my best guess, this is not possible.